# How to add conflict replace for this table in sqlite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am having trouble adding on conflict replace for a Unique on two keys:

Here is the table:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_USERS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + KEY_USER_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_IS_TYPE + " INTEGER,"
        + KEY_DATE_ADDED + " LONG,"
        + "UNIQUE (" + KEY_USER_ID + ", " + KEY_IS_TYPE + ")"
        + ")";
```

How I insert them in Android SQLite Helper

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 return db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
```

I tried doing `UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE` but it does not work.

Comment: What means `but it does not work`? any error messages?

Comment: I'd use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`

Comment: @Jens I do not remember getting one let me see and post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html), the conflict clause must come after the column list:

```
...
UNIQUE (UserID, IsType) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```

Comment: Ah ok, that is what I was trying to understand, thanks!